# Unpivoting Columns in Power Query create useless rows of data

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop, m

I have a huge table that contains reporting information. In this table, I have added 4 columns that represent the duration of specific processes. First column shows the amount of minutes ran from the start of the execution until the end of the hour, second one shows the minutes from the next hour until the end and two more columns that show the starting hour and the end hour. While trying to unpivot both couples of similar information, cases that have more than 0 minutes in the second column create unwanted rows of data, that add up to wrong sums in the visual. How can this be avoided?

Tldr; Table starts like this:

| MinToH | MinFromH | StartH | EndH |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 0 | 7 | 7 |
| 20 | 15 | 8 | 9 |

After unpivoting the Hours and removing duplicates, it changes to this:

| MinToH | MinFromH | Hours |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 0 | 7 |
| 20 | 15 | 8 |
| 20 | 15 | 9 |

And finally, after unpivoting the minutes, it looks like this:

| Minutes | Hours |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | 7 |
| 0 | 7 |
| 20 | 8 |
| 15 | 8 |
| 20 | 9 |
| 15 | 9 |

I need it to look like this:

| Minutes | Hours |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | 7 |
| 0 | 7 |
| 20 | 8 |
| 15 | 9 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    Custom1 = Table.FromColumns( {Source[MinToH]&Source[MinFromH], Source[StartH]&Source[EndH]}, {"Minutes", "Hours"})
in
    Custom1
```

Answer (score 1):

While it's not the requirement for this question, I wanted to share that you could also achieve this with regular worksheet functions (using Office 365):

`=VSTACK({"Hours","Minutes"},HSTACK(TOCOL(TAKE(Tldr,,2)),TOCOL(DROP(Tldr,,2))))`

This would change live if the table gets updated.